# Iterate over your own objects (the easy way...)

Tags: c#, oop

It seems like I remember an interface that can be implemented that basically has one method that has to return an `IEnumerable` object, and implementing this interface will allow you use `foreach` over your object.  Can someone tell me what this interface is, or correct me if I'm mis-remembering about this?

Edit: Sorry guys, I just realized I'm mixing two things up in my head.  I don't think what I just asked for exists, but what I was (and am still) trying to think of is an interface you can implement instead of either IList or IEnumerable (I forget which) that has a method which lets you just return an object of that type rather than actually implementing the IList (or IEnumerable?) interface.

So... slightly different question but still just as relevant to me.

EDIT: IListSource is what I was trying to think of.  Sorry everyone for the poorly thought out question.  Ah well, they can't all be good :)

Comment: um... google? [IEnmumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx)

Comment: Thanks IanNorton, I never would have thought of that.

Comment: @IanNorton Thanks, that will help offset the downvote I just got from whoever just (correctly) realized what a crappy question this is :)

Comment: @IanNorton Guess you should have posted your google suggestion as an answer... cause that's how I finally found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<T> has one method to return an IEnumerator<T>

IEnumerator<T> has methods like MoveNext and Current
```

Comment: Yes, its an implementation of the GoF iterator pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) (or the generic equivalent, [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)) which has a `GetEnumerator` method, returning either [`IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) or [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx).

When you implement that method, you can either call `GetEnumerator` on another collection (e.g. a list within your own class) or you can use [*iterator blocks*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) to perform more custom iteration.

If you run into any problems doing what you need to, post more details and we can help more.

Comment: I mixed up functionality in my head and realized I was actually thinking of something else, but something else that I would equally be interested in re-remembering.  As noted in my edit above, the thing I was trying to remember was an interface for implementing IList (or IEnumerable?) by simply returning an object of that type rather than actually having to implement it yourself.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: That wouldn't actually implement the interface though; you'd still need to call the method... it's not really clear what you meant, to be honest.

Comment: I agree... it's a really horrible question and it wouldn't hurt my feelings a bit if it got closed.  At least I managed to get everything straightened out in my head and accomplished the stuff I was trying to do.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Objects which implements `IEnumberable` (generic `IEnumberable<T>`) need to implement `GetEnumerator`. Using the method you get strongly typed `IEnumerator` and in case of `IEnumberable<T>` using method you will get generic `IEnumerator`.

`IEnumerator` provides methods like

- `MoveNext` which yields the next item in the collection
- `Reset` which resets the enumerator to its initial position, which is before the first element in the collection.

using which you can iterate over the collection.

Comment: There's no "b" in "IEnumerable"

Comment: Thanks. Got confused with two methods in case of `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

The `EInumerable<T>` interface (and the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface) is used to make classes enumerable.

You can implement `IEnumerable<T>` like this:

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<Item> {

  public IEnumerator<Container<T>> GetEnumerator() {

    // here you return your items, for example by returning an enumerator:
    return someArray.GetEnumerator();

    // or by using yield return:
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      yield return new Item(i);
    }

  }

  // this is needed, because IEnumerable<T> inherits IEnumerable
  System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    // uses the generic implementation
    return GetEnumerator();
  }

}
```

#### Edit:

The `foreach` statement uses duck typing, and not the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, so you don't really need to implement the interface to use a class in a `foreach` statement. You just implement the `GetEnumerator` method.

Comment: Looks like I just barely missed getting my edit in soon enough for you to read before answering... :/  Sorry bout that.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator blocks allow you to "yield return" objects of type `T` rather than creating a type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  For example:

```
IEnumerable<int> PrimesLessThanTen()
{
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
    yield return 5;
    yield return 7;
}
```

or

```
IEnumerable<byte> OddBytes()
{
    byte b = 1;
    do
    {
        yield return b;
        b += 2;
    } while (b != 1);
}
```